# How to send Javascript/HTML from site?

Tags: javascript, forms, email

We're testing out the Zendesk software trial and are wondering if we can customize the Request Submit form. Basically out of the box, we can change the fields on the form but we want more customization so we are trying to create our own form and use it as a widget.

Basically I am trying a very simple form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>   
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>      
    <title>Form Page: sampleform</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample form page</h1> 

        <form id='sampleform' method='post' action='' >
        <p>Name: <input type='text' name='Name' /></p>    
        <p>Email: <input type='text' name='Email' /></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></p>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

BUT now I am confused how to send this form....basically I know there needs to be a method and action in the form tag, but what would I use as the action? Since Zendesk is not our software, is there a way I can still use their back end script to submit the form? Basically the form would be sent to support@company.com so even if I don't use Zendesk's back end script, can I create my own to send the form request to support@company.com???

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks guys!

EDIT:---------10/10/2012--------------

Ok so after further research and following what Noah said I created a PHP like this to submit my form data. I also modified the original form as seen below...

--PHP Script
    
    PHP Mail Sender

```
    if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $email)) {
        echo "<h4>Invalid email address</h4>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
    } elseif ($subject == "") {
        echo "<h4>No subject</h4>";
        echo "<a href='javascript:history.back(1);'>Back</a>";
    } elseif (mail($to,$subject,$description)) {
        echo "<h4>Thank you for your email</h4>";
    } else {
        echo "<h4>Can't send email to $email</h4>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

--HTML Form

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>   
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>      
    <title>Form Page: Support</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Support Form Page</h1> 

    <form id='supportform' method='POST' action='supportMail.php' ></p>   
            <p>Subject: <input type='text' name='subject' /></p>    
            <p>Email: <input type='text' name='email' /></p>
            <p>Description: <input type='text' name='description' /></p>
            <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></p>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

No I might be a complete noob at this but where should I put the PHP script and how do I reference it in the form? I know its in the action section of  but do I need to include a URL or just the script name.

The thing that confuses me is that the website the Form will be on and the Script are on different servers...and the server the script is on is a Windows Server...I installed PHP onto the Windows Server but I don't understand where I need to put the script.

Comment: im sorry im a little confused. what do you want to do with the data that is filled out in the form after it is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to you a PHP file to send the data.

**HTML**

```
<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='file.php' > // make sure the 'action' is equal to the name of the PHP file 
        <p>Name: <input type='text' name='Name' /></p>    
        <p>Email: <input type='text' name='Email' /></p>
        <p><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' /></p>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // name that is submitted from the form
$email = $_POST['email']; // email that is submitted from the form

// mail function so yo can email information to someone with data that was submitted through the form 
mail('[enter the TO email here]','[Enter the subject here]','[enter the email message here]');
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to send the form data to an email such as support@company.com....where do I put the PHP file? Does that need to go on our web server? Or for example, since we are using Zendesk which is Software as a Service, does it need to be on their web server?

Comment: it doesnt matter the external script that you are using from Zendesk. All you are doing is taking the information from the form and emailing it to `support@company.com` correct? You will need to place the PHP file anywhere you like on your server but make sure that you refrence it correctly in the `action` part of the form though.

Comment: oh ok, thats exactly what I needed to know! I will give this a try early next week and report back if it works!! Thank you Noah. I will mark it as solved or ask you for more details haha.

Comment: Hi Noah, I need some help again...please see the original post for details as I just updated it. Basically I have no clue where to put the script on our Windows Server and how to use it in action=''. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ok in the form, you put `supportMail.php`. Now inorder to refrence the PHP script that you created, you need to put the script into a new document with the name and extension `supportMail.php`. For the refencing to work correctly both the files need to be in the same folder on the server. If they are not in the same folder that is an esay fix to refrence to it. Basically thats all that needs to be done. It should work. However, the PHP that you posted to the update is not actually sending an email.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, and want some more help, you can email me at `passa@gmx.com` Could you please mark this as the correct answer! thanks :)